# Meaning of "bust"

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns

Context ([New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/18/science/space/18starship.html?_r=1&ref=science)),

> Alpha Centauri or **bust**. The government agency that helped invent the Internet now wants to do the same for travel to the stars. ...

Does *bust* here mean

> [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bust):  8. failure

Is the author saying that either the government agency is going to pull this off (sending humans to Alpha Centauri, to the stars) or this is just totally a failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bust* in this context typically means *I/We will collapse from the effort*. So it's almost like saying:

> We will get to Alpha Centauri or die trying.

<sub>source: [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/or+bust)</sub>

Comment: I've always been a bit perplexed by the related **shit or bust** (meaning *all or nothing*) where both alternatives seem to imply impending failure.

Comment: Note that in the heavily capitalist society of the USA, "going broke" and "die trying" aren't really all that different.

Answer (score 2):

**Once committed there is no turning back.**

In the days of westward colonization families would load everything they owned into wagons and head west with the intent of carving out a living and making their fortune.

The phrase dates back to the [California gold rush of 1849](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Gold_Rush). (It may go back further than that). Check out [page 240 of the History of California Vol.3 by Theodore Hittell](http://ia600302.us.archive.org/17/items/historycaliforn20hittgoog/historycaliforn20hittgoog.pdf):

> The large canvas-covered wagons were called "prairie schooners", and
>   many of them carried mottoes such as "California or bust," "No return
>   tickets by this line," or something equally as expressive but
>   unrefined.